# How to pass r-value of an environment variable as a CLI argument for an NPM script

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress, package.json

**Goal**: Is there a way or hack that lets me add r-value of an environment variable as a CLI argument for an NPM script **without calling a separate script**?

**Example**:

- Script: `"test:run": cypress run --spec 'tests/*' --env host=`
- Usage: `npm run test:run localhost`
- Expectation: `cypress run --spec 'tests/*' --env host=localhost`

What I use currently is:

- Script: `"test:run": cypress run --spec 'tests/*' --env`
- Usage: `npm run test:run host=localhost`
- Result: `cypress run --spec 'tests/*' --env host=localhost`

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to even omit adding `host=` in my command so I can just write the r-value, `localhost` for brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that what you want to achieve is currently possible how you want to achieve it, because of how npm breaks out command-line arguments. Anything passed in is appended as a separate "option", instead of just added to the existing string, which is the behavior you're currently seeing (`npm run test:run localhost` => `cypress run --spec 'tests/*' --env host= localhost`).

There are a few alternatives, which seem to be what you don't want to do, but you could create a separate script for that behavior.

```
"test:run": "cypress run --spec 'tests/*' --env"
"test:run:local": "npm run test:run host=localhost"
```

Or, you could declare the Cypress environment variable before the test command.

```sh
CYPRESS_HOST=localhost npm run test:run
```